# How to simulate HOLDING a keystroke in Keyboard Maestro?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keystroke, keyboard-maestro

Using Keyboard Maestro 5, I want to be able to simulate holding a specific key for a specific amount of time for one of my macros. I am not sure if this is currently possible, and I have yet to find a work around. Any help would be appreciated in how this may be done.

Answer (score 2):

An old post, but a common question about Keyboard Maestro.

Good news and bad news.
Bad news first:

The developer of Keyboard Maestro (currently version 7) says,

> "No, Keyboard Maestro cannot press and hold any button or key."

Now the good news.
Another poster on that forum says:

> Karabiner is perfect ... Define a key combo in Karabiner and map this to your KM macro.

[Here is the link to that topic on the Keyboard Maestro forum.](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/press-and-hold-keystroke/1004/2?u=mark)